# How can we merge previous commit on main branch in git?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a `main branch` and another branch called `release 1`.

I made `release 1` branch from `main branch`, then I made 5 more commits.

Now, I want to merge changes till the 3rd commit to the `main branch`. How can I merge the 3rd commit with main branch?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the commits are in the order you want, so you could do:

```
git merge release1~2
```

That would chose the grandparent of the release1 branch's tip (the 3rd commit, if there are 5 extra), or you could simply do:

```
git merge $ID_OF_3RD_COMMIT
```

Where `$ID_OF_3RD_COMMIT` is the commit id for the 3rd commit in the release branch.

Both of these assume that the first, second, and third commits are the ones you want to keep.  Otherwise, you'll definitely want to follow the cherry-pick solution.